# Notification screen issue

Tags: android, notifications

I am working on an android application. In my app I am using nottification. I have two screens screen1 and screen2.  Whenever notification came .If we click on the notification in will lead to screen2.
Now my problem is if I am in screen2. One new notification came and click on the notification will open screen 2 .Then the click on the back button will display the screen2 again. Because click on the notification open screen2 infront of previous screen2. How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this Flag Value to your Notification Intent,

```
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

This will ensure that if your called Activity is on Top of the Stack no new Instance of it will be created, instead it just helps you to move to that Activity.

Comment: Now New activity wont open if we already in same activity.But I want to open the new activity and want to close the old activity.Because new intent come with the new values.

Comment: Can you try with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP alone?

Answer (score 3):

you should just define your activity as single instance in your manifest file

```
 <activity android:name=".Screen2"
       android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

using `launchMode` will prevent the activity from being launched several times.